# How to install kaspersky on the other os in a multi-boot computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, kaspersky

I have a laptop with windows vista and windows 7 as the os.
The vista has an installation of kaspersky antivirus 2009 with original license. Since I am not using Vista frequently, can I transfer or make use of that installation on windows vista to be utilize by Windows 7? Without having to uninstall it from vista and reinstall it on 7?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Being two completely different OS's with no relationship whatsoever except being on the same computer... Uninstalling and reinstalling might be the best option, unless your kaspersky license is multi-computer (many are nowadays, e.g. Mcafee = "protect three computers") and you don't mind using up another of those licenses to install on windows 7 without uninstalling on Vista.